# Why does MySQL Slow Queries Log not exist?

Tags: mysql, centos, logging

I was looking today on my CentOS server for a MySQL Slow Queries Log, but have had no luck finding the log. I even did a "SELECT SLEEP(2)" test in hopes to have this file created. Take note, I am not very server savvy so any help is appreciated.

```
 7
  8 [mysql.server]
  9 user=mysql
 10 basedir=/var/lib
 11
 12 [mysqld]
 13 long_query_time = 1
 14 log_slow_queries=/var/log/mysql_slow_queries.log
 15 log=/var/log/mysql.query.log
 16
 17 ## FINE TUNING ##
 18
 19 key_buffer              = 16M
 20 max_allowed_packet      = 16M
 21 thread_stack            = 128K
 22 thread_cache_size       = 8
 23 query_cache_limit       = 1M
 24 query_cache_size        = 16M
 25
 26 [mysqld_safe]
 27 log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
 28 pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 29 safe-show-databases
```

As you can see the path shows: /var/log/mysql_slow_queries.log  -- but this file is no where to be found. I have found mysql.query.log and mysqld.log just fine in the directory however. Why does my MySQL Slow Queries file not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have made the changes to your `my.cnf` file, you need to restart the MySQL service. Not sure what system you are on, but typically `service mysqld restart` will work or `service mysql restart` -- just look in `/etc/init.d/`.

In addition, make sure the file is created and available on disk:

```
touch /var/log/mysql_slow_queries.log
chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql_slow_queries.log
```

In addition, time is not so important in databases but rather queries with no indices. Consider adding the following to your `my.cnf`. Of course, restart MySQL once you do:

`log-queries-not-using-indexes`

Comment: why you are using chown recursive on a file?

Comment: @c4f4t0r muscle reflex

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I wish I could have chosen both answers as the selected answer, because both were helpful. I greatly appreciate the help; both answers worked out great.

Answer (score 0):

touch /var/log/mysql_slow_queries.log

chown mysql:mysql

and restart your mysql service

mysql -u -pmypassword

select sleep(60);

cat /var/log/mysql_slow_queries.log

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.28-log (Source distribution). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 130904 23:22:14
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 60.002284  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1378329734;
select sleep(60);
```

Answer (score 0):

add `slow_query_log=1` to the `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf` and restart mysqld.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, in Centos 7, as default and without a MySQL restart, the slow query log is enabled in this position:

```
/var/lib/mysql/$HOSTNAME.log
```

See the other answers to discover how to apply your persistent configuration and how to move it to another position.